# Concatenating two columns of text Alphabetically in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, concatenation, alphabetical-sort

I am working with this spreadsheet of airport data.Sorry can't figure out how to format the headers, but first column is Origin IATA, 2nd is Dest IATA, and 3rd if Concatenate Route

```
Origin IATA,       Dest IATA,       Concatenate Route

LHR                JFK              LHR-JFK
JFK                LHR              JFK-LHR
CAN                PEK              CAN-PEK
PEK                CAN              PEK-CAN
JFK                LAX              JFK-LAX
LHR                DXB              LHR-DXB
DXB                LHR              DXB-LHR
```

Picture version:

[image]

Right now, I just have =CONCATENATE(C:C,"-",D:D) as the formula, but I actually need them to concatenate in alphabetical order so I can collapse CAN-PEK as one round trip route.

I found someone with a similar question here: [Excel formula to take values from cell range, sort alphabetically and write as a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672155/excel-formula-to-take-values-from-cell-range-sort-alphabetically-and-write-as-a)

And I tried to modify the code of the accepted answer, but I keep getting errors because I don't know what I'm doing. I also tried VBA code, doing it in access, and many other Stackoverflow solutions, but I am stuck.

Does anyone know how I need to write the code to get it to do what I want?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Excel one can use mathematical inequalities for text strings in many cases. In C2 put:

```
=IF(A2<B2,A2&"-"&B2,B2&"-"&A2)
```

Then copy down

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer, and helped me with a similar issue. In my case I wanted to create a Participant field using To and From fields that I could then sort as a group.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When using a formula, you would need to use your existing formula as a helper column and then add the final column containing the sorted results. The example below has the named range "concat" assigned to the concatenate column and the named range "order" assigned to the sort order column.

Note, if your data is in an Excel structured table, you don't need to use defined names. You can select table column and Excel will insert the proper syntax.

Sort Order Column (column E, copy down)

```
=COUNTIF(concat,"<="&E2)
```

Alpha Sorted Column (column F, copy down)

```
=INDEX(concat,MATCH(ROWS($E$2:E2),order,0))
```